# Connecting to the same server that hosts my OpenVPN server, resolves, and uses my original ip address

Tags: configuration, ip, require, openvpn

I have an openvpn server hosted on my vps, on which I also host one of my web servers.
On this web server I would like to configure a route to be only accessible from my vpn.
Is it possible to resolve the vpn client ip as the server ip if the client wants to connect to the server on which the vpn itself is being hosted?

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I use debian 9 on my vps

Comment: related forum https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=7514

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the internal ip for the remote server in the local hosts file when connected to the vpn. This way [as i saw in the access.log] you will be connecting to the apache server over the internal ip